# Gstreamer: Stream low latency video from Raspberry Pi (Tx) to Raspberry Pi (Rx)

Tags: linux, streaming-video, gstreamer

**Goal**

I'm working on a project with modules. A module contains for example a Raspberry Pi and some additional hardware.

What I'm currently trying to do is using the camera of Pi A as input and stream this with low latency to Pi B. So that I will be able to see it in a window.

The connection must go over ethernet (I have Gigabit switches available)

**My solution**

I found something called [Gstreamer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/). By entering commands in the terminal you can send or receive a specific stream with latencies up to 30ms!

**Problem**

The documentation is not so understandable and I tried a lot of tutorials but I just can't get it working.
Could somebody give me an example or a clear explenation of how gstreamer works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a usefull tutorial that gives some examples: [Here](http://www.einarsundgren.se/gstreamer-basic-real-time-streaming-tutorial/)

Transmitter:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v ximagesrc use-damage=false xname=/usr/lib/torcs/torcs-bin ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,format=I420,width=800,height=600,framerate=25/1 ! jpegenc ! rtpjpegpay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

Receiver:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp,encoding-name=JPEG,payload=26 ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegdec ! autovideosink
```